# Replace multiple occurrences of a Special character with a Single character

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to replace Special character with Underscore. Issue I'm facing is instead of replacing with single underscore there are 2 underscores appearing. Below is my code.

```
String string = "Sathesh, Soundar";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("[,\\s]","_"));
```

Here i'm getting the output as `Sathesh__Soundar`. Instead of this i want to get `Sathesh_Soundar`. If I have some more continues special characters everything should be replaced with single underscore.

Comment: Use `+` quantifier `"[,\\s]+"`

Comment: I'll suggest [`[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/lH9BSs/1)

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for the quick response. I like the 2nd option `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to define what is special character. I assume you define this as - all characters except alpha numeric. Then the regex should be `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`

This regex is explained as [here](https://regex101.com/r/gM70Vh/3).

And then the code should be as below

```
String string = "Sathesh, Soundar";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","_"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\d]+", "_");
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the space after the ',' for your desired output with single underscore.

```
 String string = "Sathesh,Soundar"; //prints Sathesh_Soundar
```

Comment: Gee, why not just change the string to `String string = "Sathesh_Soundar";` and be done with it?